# use reference in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use reference in std::map

```
typedef const std::function<void(const cocos2d::Ref*)>& callBack;

std::map<const std::string&, callBack> m_mapListener
```

and my error message is:

```
error C2535: 'const std::function<void (const cocos2d::Ref *)> &std::map<const std::string &,callBack,
std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<_Kty,_Ty>>>::operator [](const std::basic_string
<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' : 
member function already defined or declared 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\map
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `std::function`. Next time perform some experimentation, such as taking away the `std::function` and seeing whether your problem remains (which it does). Also, present proper [testcases](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions: here your error message complains about `operator[]`, but you don't ever show us actually using `operator[]`. It's pure chance that we can fix the problem for you regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `map` as:

```
std::map<std::string, callBack> m_mapListener;
```

STL containers don't support references because they require that their element type meets the requirements of Erasable, in which case references don't.